# Gradient type error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a glow effect by using a gradient.

In my XML I have this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#7AD8FF" />

        <gradient android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" android:endColor="#7AD8FF" android:type="radial"/>

        <stroke android:width="0dp"  android:color="#7AD8FF"/>

        <corners android:radius="20dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#D1D1D1" />

        <corners android:radius="0dp" />

        <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

When I try to set "android:type="radial"", it causes an error...

...Any ideas?

Comment: what error does it cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying **android:gradientRadius**:

```
<gradient 
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" 
    android:endColor="#7AD8FF" 
    android:type="radial" 
    android:gradientRadius="100" 
/>
```